# Count all transactions per day with select sum

Tags: mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I already did  the select sum. My target is to show in my table all of the count of transactions grouped by day. For example; `On date 2021-06-04, I had 5 transactions. Now, I need to show that in my table (total transaction column). Same to other transactions` I have provided my codes below and my screenshot for more explanation. Is there anything i missed? Hope you can help me. Thank you in advance, appreciated.

[image]

views:

```
<table  id="perDay" class="table table-bordered table-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth "  style="min-width:1000px; width:100%;">
                            <thead class="" style="background-color: #404040; color: white;">
                                <tr>
                                  <th scope="col"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt mr-2"></i>Date</th>
                                 <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-user-tie mr-2"></i>Total Transaction</th> 
                                  <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-user-tie mr-2"></i>Amount</th> 
                                  
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
            
                     
                  </table>
```

controller:

```
    public function fetch_dash()

{

    $list = $this->statistics->fetchperDay();
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $person) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
     
        $row[] = $person->dateUp;
        $row[] = $person->transID;
        $row[] = number_format($person->amount);
        
        
        //add html for action
    
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    
    $output = array(
        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
        "recordsTotal" => $this->statistics->allShow(),
        "recordsFiltered" => $this->statistics->filterAll(),
        "data" => $data,
    );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
   


}
```

model:

```
 function fetchperDay()
    {
        $this->perDay();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
            $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
    }
    
    private function perDay()
    {
        
        
        $this->db->select('tbl_transaction.transID,tbl_transaction.amount,tbl_transaction.dateUp,tbl_transaction.transID');
        $this->db->from('tbl_transaction');
        $this->db->select_sum('tbl_transaction.amount');
        $this->db->group_by('tbl_transaction.dateUp');
        
        
    }
```

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Comment: I've already did https://prnt.sc/14bq9eb , but when I do both counts and select sum the error comes.

Comment: I don't really do pictures

Comment: I provided my query in my model above. Please see it thank you.